# Monitoring two application servers behind a firewall

Tags: monitoring, http

I want to monitor that our Tomcat application servers is up and running. The application is not hosted in-house, but at a managed hosting provider. I do not have direct access to the application servers, but I can access them through a login-server.

What is the simplest way to send an HTTP request to see if the Tomcat application servers is up?

I already have a monitor system in-house (`sensu`), but this system does not have direct access to the Tomcat servers either. It can only be accessed through the login-server.

```
                             +---------------+
                      +------+ Apache Server +------+
                      |      +---------------+      |
                      |                             |
                      |                             |
                  +---v-----------+     +-----------v---+
                  | Tomcat Server |     | Tomcat Server |
                  |    RFC1918    |     |    RFC1918    |
                  +---------------+     +---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to add a couple of proxy/rewrite-rules in Apache, that would give you one URL for each Tomcat.

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html

Then you can use an ordinary http-probe on those URLs.  The probes may give a false positive for the application servers if Apache is down, but that may be acceptable.  This again can be remedied by setting up dependencies - Icinga at least, supports Service dependencies.